# Custom domain names - heroku

Tags: heroku

This doesn't work for some reason.

I have my heroku app: example.herokuapp.com

And my custom domain name: example.com

My settings in heroku seem to be correct. My dashboard says the domain name is example.com and the dns target is example.herokuapp.com

The settings in the control panel for my custom domain name seem right too; url forwarding is set to example.herokuapp.com and the forward mode is: frame(cloaking) default

Answer (score 0):

First list your heroku domains, then follow the steps, and reference the guide linked below.

```
heroku domains
```

## General steps:

1. Confirm that you own the custom domain name. If not, you can buy one with a domain registration service.
2. Add the custom domain to your app with the heroku domains:add command. See below for different variations.
3. Look up the Heroku-supplied DNS Target for the custom domain using the heroku domains command as described below.
4. Configure your app’s DNS provider to point to the Heroku-supplied DNS Target.
5. Test that your app is accessible via the custom domain. There may be a delay while DNS changes propagate.

[Check this out](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all that (should've mentioned it). Just doesn't seem to want to go.