# Heroku - can't set up custom domain name

Tags: heroku, dns

I have the same problem as [tdrsam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472828/custom-domain-names-heroku), but it went unanswered so I am posting my own version. I have a heroku app and my own domain name registered with Godaddy. I have followed [the guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#view-existing-domains) referenced in similar posts. After using `$ heroku domains:add`, a check `$ heroku domains` shows my app has a custom domain with my registered domain name and a DNS target name (domain name with `.herokudns.com` tacked on). Following the guide, at Godaddy I entered the DNS target in the CNAME record for www.  Back in the Heroku CLI, the first time I do `host <myappname>` I get 2 lines that say `<myappname> has address <IP number>` with 2 slightly different IP numbers and a line saying `<myappname> not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. Godaddy tells me I need an A record which has to be an IP address, so I created 2 A records with the 2 IP addresses from the host command.  Now when I do another host command, there is no "app not found" message, but one saying `<myappname> mail is by...`, which must be the DNS MX record. BUT, `<myappname>` entered in a browser is not found. I have waited hours for the DNS to propagate--am I being impatient, or should I have seen something more positive with the host command?

Comment: I'm not an expert with Heroku/GoDaddy, but I think that you should be able to add the Public IP you exposed from Heroku, in the GoDaddy dashboard under an advanced DNS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to reference the IP addresses directly, and doing so is very likely to be problematic as they could change.

The best thing to do is to forward your root domain to `www` (see GoDaddy instructions on that here: https://ph.godaddy.com/help/forward-a-domain-12123)

Alternatively, use a service like http://wwwizer.com/ to set your A record to forward to www.

Comment: Yes, I mistook something in the Heroku guide for having to set the A record.  I got rid of that now, but I don't know if I have to do something else, at either end, to retry the connection.  It's frustrating when you don't know how long you have to wait to see if the DNS propagated.   I have reasons I want to assign the custom domain name to the Heroku app instead of using Godaddy's forwarding.